# How to disable input zoom in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

Can someone help me to get rid of automatic zoom while typing in input field of my website that is shown in WKWebView?

Comment: What kind of zoom?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code , it works for me :

```
let source: String = "var meta = document.createElement('meta');" +
            "meta.name = 'viewport';" +
            "meta.content = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no';" +
            "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];" + "head.appendChild(meta);";

        let script: WKUserScript = WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
        webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
```

Comment: for anyone else reading, this works, but will disable not just the auto-zoom, but also the zoom with fingers. However, you have my vote!